# Borders not showing on print preview (tables)

Tags: html, html-table

So I was given an assingment to create an A4 sheet with html and I thought the best way to

```css
@media all{
    th{
        padding-right:35px;
        border:2px solid black;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr{
    border:2px solid black;   
}

td{
    border:2px solid black;   
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Provider</th>
                <th>T-Mobile DE</th>
                <th>T-Mobile DE</th>
                <th>T-Mobile DE</th>
                <th>T-Mobile DE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Technology</td>
                <td>GSM</td>
                <td>LTE</td>
                <td>Technology</td>
                <td>GSM</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Band(s)</td>
                <td>900
                    1800</td>
                <td>1
                    2
                    3
                    4
                    </td>
                <td>Band(s)</td>
                <td>Band(s)</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

do that was tables.
However the borders are not showing when I i switch to print preview, unless I use border : 2px solid black; but then they are too thick.
I used media all{} and normal css but still doesnt work. Could someone help me?

Comment: Probably you forgot to put ```<!DOCTYPE html>``` at the begining

Answer (score 1):

I tried `border: 3px solid black;` and the problem went away.

Answer (score -3):

I tried using the following border-style in Chrome and Safari:

```
border:1px solid black;
```

The borders were showing in the print-preview.
Might this is a bug in your specific browser?

Comment: It might also be the screen.  The dpi of the device might have been to low to display it and anti-aliasing just cut it out.